# Understanding やったろうじゃねえか

Tags: grammar, colloquial-language, anime

From No Game No life (Anime)

Context: this gamer guy is pretty pissed that his sister is falling asleep and afraid that he's gonna die in the game, but then she falls asleep, and gets hyped/irritated and says:

> やったろうじゃねえか！

From what I can gather, じゃねえか is a colloquial form of じゃないか, but what is やったろう and how come it can attach じゃねえか if it's not a noun (or is it?).

Edit: I read the suggestions, and while the "didn't you?" meaning じゃないか makes sense, I still don't know what やったろう is supposed to mean. Based on the context of the situation, I think the meaning should be something like "you did, didn't you?!" because it's his reaction to his sister's having fallen asleep a second ago. Interestingly enough, the official translation of the sentence is "Fine, bring it on!".

Edit2: Found the solution to the meaning of the expression in the comments, but I would still like to hear a comprehensive explanation. Why does it mean what it means, i.e willingness to take on a difficult situation?

Comment: Also https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/47813/how-does-%e3%81%98%e3%82%83%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84%e3%81%8b-modify-hortative-in-this-case and https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/453/%ef%bd%9e%e3%81%9f%e3%81%98%e3%82%83%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84-expression-in-spoken-japanese

Comment: @Aeon Akechi thanks for the help, but I still don't know what やったろう is supposed to mean here.

Comment: やってやろう contracts to やったろう

Comment: @AeonAkechi Thanks a lot! I found the solution here https://hinative.com/ja/questions/4471113

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all the comments, google and J-J dictionaries, I think I've figured it out.

やったろう＝やってやろう

てやる is used here to express a strong will to do the action of the verb

てやろう＝hortative form of てやる

So to connect the pieces, やってやろう means "Let's do it!"

じゃねえか＝じゃないか (/ee/ < /ai/ transformation in informal usage)

じゃないか is used to ask for confirmation from the other party.

To finish the puzzle, it all means:

> Let's do it, shall we? - formal

> Let's freaking do it, you hear!? - in the anime.

Correct me if I'm wrong somewhere.